# Python 'NoneType' itterable in list operation

Tags: python, duplicates, iterable, nonetype

I am writing a function to remove duplication in one list. For specific:

> input : a list
>
> output: a list without any duplication

this is my code:

```
def remove_duplicate(s_list):
    for member in s_list:
        for other in s_list.remove(member):
            if other == member:
                s_list.remove(other)
    return s_list
```

After that, I try to run `remove_duplicate([1,2,3,4])` and the error is

```
for other in s_list.remove(member):
  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `list.remove` is *in-place*, it doesn't `return` anything. Also, don't modify lists while iterating over them.

Comment: You can use `list(set(s_list))` for removing duplicates.

Comment: Note, however, that `set`s don't guarantee order. You should look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/7961363/3001761

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to work with two lists instead of changing one list in-place, if possible.

If order is not important, you can use a set:

```
dup_list = [1,1,2,3,2,5,2]
dupfree_list = list(set(dup_list))
```

Otherwise, if the order of elements is important, you can note which elements you have already seen:

```
dupfree_list = []
for e in dup_list:
  if e not in dupfree_list:
    dupfree_list.append(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most Pythonic way is to use a `set` which removes duplicates:

```
listwithduplicates = [1,2,3,3]
listwithduplicates = set(listwithduplicates)
```

The result is:

```
{2,1,3}
```

Note that sets are not ordered the way lists are.

Comment: Note that `set`s aren't ordered